# Cannot connect to mysql database on my website

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I have a website that I should put on my domain.I have encountered an issue when I tried connecting to MySQL database so my code is not working. When I put

```
define("DB_HOST","http://domain");
define("DB_USER","user");
define("DB_PASS","password");
define("DB_NAME","dbName");

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
if(!$connection){
    die();
}
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
```

I get this error in log

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Plugin http could not be loaded: /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/http.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

otherwise, I tried to remove that HTTP and just use the domain as DB_HOST, but then I get error

```
 define("DB_HOST","mydomain.com");
    define("DB_USER","user");
    define("DB_PASS","password");
    define("DB_NAME","dbName");
    
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
    if(!$connection){
        die();
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
```

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'domain.com' (115) in /home3/domain/public_html/a/i.php on line 7

Can anyone please help me find the solution to make this work?

Comment: `http://domain` is wrong, and `domain.com` is wrong if the mysql server is not open to the internet and the user is allowed to connect from any host. If you're on shared hosting enter the details provided by your host. If your working on one server like a VPS and mysql is installed locally use localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the domain. You need to provide more details about the setup.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I define a MYSQLI connection;

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
```

When you want to run an operation you just invoke the $con variable.
If you have issues check the permissions for the MYSQL user, they should at the very least include;

delete
insert
select
show view
update